# from android through JSON to mysql Arabic

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, arabic

This is my Java file. I'm trying to send Arabic letters not working instead of Arabic words I get `???? ????? ?????`.

I can read Arabic from MySQL but I can't add Arabic to MySQL.

```
public class NewSecret extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputDesc;

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://laylakaylif.com/android/add_secrets.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // fullScreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Lina);

    AdView ad2 = new AdView(NewSecret.this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER,
            "a150b0de6e44a18");
    ll.addView(ad2);
    ad2.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    if (inputName.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
        inputName.setError("الرجاء اضافة عنوان!");

    if (inputDesc.getText().toString().length() <= 10)
        inputDesc.setError("الرجاء اضافة نص السر ..");

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewSecret.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("إضافة سر جديد ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String title = inputName.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        String htmltitle;
        String deshtml;

        htmltitle = TextUtils.htmlEncode(title);
        deshtml = TextUtils.htmlEncode(description);

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", htmltitle));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", deshtml));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AllSecrets.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

And this is my PHP JSON file:

```
 <?php
 header("Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8"); //global encoding since this is the config file -- for Arabic support
/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
/*if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $title = json_encode($_POST['title'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $description = json_encode($_POST['description'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
*/

if (isset($_REQUEST['title']) && isset($_REQUEST['description'])) {
    echo $_REQUEST['title'].'<br/>';
/*
    $title = json_decode($__REQUEST['title']);
    $description = json_decode($__REQUEST['description']);
*/

    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $description = $_REQUEST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    //setting the connection charset
     mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
     mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
     mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");


    // mysql inserting a new row
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO secrets(title ,  description) VALUES('$title', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Secret successfully added.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

JSONParser code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);
```

I don't know what JSONParser you are using. It's not part of the standard platform; there are dozens of different classes littered about the web with that name, many of which include a line like:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

This is a problem because the [default](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.html#DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET) encoding for a `UrlEncodedFormEntity` is ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8. If you want to pass UTF-8, [include](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html#UrlEncodedFormEntity%28java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20org.apache.http.NameValuePair%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) it as a parameter:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```

If that's not the problem, suggest posting the JSONParser code.

Comment: I think i got what is wrong  .. // i have to send with the POST
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8")); not just httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

Comment: ok now the Arabic characters pass to mysql but i get this error from catLog 


11-26 18:49:45.219: E/JSON Parser(28867): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»ï»¨ïºªï»£ïº of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

and the app just crashes ..

Comment: @AhmedAkour you should also change in the `JSONParser` code the line with `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);` to  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);`

Answer (score 2):

for how looking to solve the problem of posting non Latina Charcter (Arabic or others), Use this command in your php page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

mysql_query("CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
```

And for sure you must use UTF in your httpeEntity, Also your MySQL Databse must be encoded with UTF-8

i hope this offer some information for who looking for same issue

Answer (score 0):

just make the collation utf8_general_ci